# Ignore collisions from all objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to check if there is a way to ignore collisions on an object completely. The object however will still have its rigidbody, but will not collide with anything. I know that `Physics.IgnoreCollision` is the way to do it but looks like I have to provide colliders from each object. What is the right way to do this?

```
Physics.IgnoreCollision(null, GetComponent<BoxCollider>());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about simply turning of its collider component?

```
GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;
```

---

Another alternative would be to configure a dedicated [Layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html), configure it in the [Physics Settings -> Layer Collision Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicsManager.html) to not collide with anything and temporarily assign that layer to your object

```
gameObject.layer = xy;
```